# NHibernate - pessimistic locking not working

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, pessimistic-locking

Follow up of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246051/nhibernate-counters-with-concurrency-and-second-level-caching).

I'm trying to implement pessimistic locking for a concurrency issue as I described in the question above (please, feel free to add to that one). But it's not working for me.

I do a very simple test: I have two seperate sites running that both increase a counter 500 times. I run them simultaneously. In the end, I expect that a certain column in my table has, you guess it, a value of 1000.

Here is the code. It's no production code of course, but test code or not, it should still work, right?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
  var tx = this.userRepo.Session.BeginTransaction();
  var user = this.userRepo.GetById(42);
  user.Counter++;
  userRepo.Save(user);
  tx.Commit();
}
```

The `GetById` method uses LockMode.Upgrade:

```
public T GetById(int id)
{
  T obj = Session.Get<T>(id, LockMode.Upgrade);
  return obj;
}
```

Now, using NHProfiler I see the following SQL statement:

`SELECT Id FROM 'User' WHERE Id = 42 for update`

but the result is a value of around **530**, so that's about half of the updates lost due to concurrency. What am I doing wrong? I disabled second level cache in this test. Am I using the wrong lock mode? Should I specify an isoliation level? Anything else? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** FluentNhibernate config:

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionstring))
.Mappings(m => assemblyTypes.Select(t => t.Assembly).ToList().ForEach(a => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(a)))
.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.Properties.Add("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none"));
```

Comment: Can you post your Nhibernate config code?

Comment: @UpTheCreek: using FluentNH, not sure what you want to see, but I included it

Answer (score 0):

For the `LockMode.Upgrade` to work, all transactions have to be enclosed in a transaction because what `LockMode.Upgrade` does is lock it into the current transaction.

Your problem will most likely be due to the statements not being enclosed in a transaction.

Optimistic locking does not apply to a single statement, but to multiple transactions that are separated from each other. An example:

1. Begin a transaction;
2. Get record by `Id = 42`;
3. End the transaction.

Then, outside of the transaction, increase `Counter`.

After that:

1. Begin a transaction;
2. Get record by `Id = 42`;
3. Check whether counter has been unchanged from the value received in the first transaction;

   a. If it hasn't changed, update the counter with the increased value;

   b. If it has changed, handle the changed value.
4. End the transaction.

Optimistic locking means that you "hope" the `Counter` hasn't changed between the two transactions and handle the case where it has changed. With pessimistic locking, you ensure that all changes are done within a single transaction with all required records locked.

B.t.w.: the checking mechanism (whether `Counter` has changed in the mean time) can be automatically handled by NHibernate.

Comment: Look at my code - I use BeginTransaction() and Commit() in the end. That's what you mean, right?

Comment: Apologies, you're right. What's your serialization mode (the connection.isolation SessionFactory setting or the first parameter to `BeginTransaction`). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx for more information on their meaning. Try to play with these and see whether that makes a difference. See what happens with `Serializable` because that should guarantee that this works as expected.

Comment: hmmm, maybe using the for-loop was also causing problems. It seems with no for-loop but using Thread.Sleep to cause concurrency, I do get good results using IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead and LockMode.Upgrade. Still, if you can clarify how these different mechanisms and those difference types work together, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I will have to refer you to documentation on these isolation levels because it's too much to handle this in a comment :). Note however that the MSDN link itself also has some information, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems) will probably provide more information.